# Custom domain with AppEngine and Firebase auth email templates

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication, email-templates, custom-domain

I have an AppEngine app that uses Firebase auth to manage users.

I recently added a custom domain to the AppEngine app, and that worked fine.

Now I'm trying to manage the Password Reset template and change the sender email to match my domain. But when I follow the instructions to add the 2 TXT records and 2 CNAME records, the verification never completes. It's been in this state for almost 2 days. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Instructions are:

[image]

Comment: The issue still persist? Sometimes the DNS records propagation takes up to 24-48 hours.

Comment: I had the same issue, this is what worked for me.  The Value fields were not changed.
I used @ as the Host for the TXT records.
Remove your domain from the CNAME Host fields.
firebase1._domainkey
firebase2._domainkey

Answer (score 0):

Edit the DNS settings Firebase provided to match these patterns:

**CNAME 1**

```
HOST:   firebase1._domainkey
VALUE:  mail-YOURDOMAIN-com.dkim1._domainkey.firebasemail.com.
```

**CNAME 2**

```
HOST:   firebase2._domainkey
VALUE:  mail-YOURDOMAIN-com.dkim2._domainkey.firebasemail.com.
```

**TXT 1**

```
HOST:   @
VALUE:  v=spf1 include:_spf.firebasemail.com ~all
```

**TXT 2**

```
HOST:   @
VALUE:  firebase=YOURDOMAIN
```